# Split XML with XSLT 1.0 at the location of a particular tag, and maintain HTML markup throughout results

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I need to transform the following XML by splitting at the `<hr/>` tag. The content on either side of the split should then be stored as params, and output within separate divs.

I'm running into several issues:

1) I can't seem to use the `<hr/>` tag as the separator for this. I assume that's due to the parser stripping the tag prior to setting the new params? Is there a workaround for this? I do have control over the XML output within the `<bodyText>` node, and while I could use a specified string instead, the `<hr/>` tag makes for a more reliable flag maintenance-wise.

2) While `<xsl:copy-of select="$desc"/>` produces the full contents with HTML markup intact (which I need), `$shortDesc` and `$longDesc` both return the bare / stripped text content. How can I retain the HTML markup?

**Essentially I need to split the XML at the point of the `<hr/>` tag, and then copy the before and after contents into separate divs with markup intact.**

I've seen a few posts with challenges quite close to this, but each just different enough that I've been unable to resolve.

The XML:

```
<bodyText>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Short</p>
  <hr/>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Long</p>
</bodyText>
```

*And please note that the XML feed is admin-generated, so this is just a basic example. The actual feed is not dependable, only that there will be an `<hr/>` for where the split should occur.

The XSL:

```
<xsl:template name="ExpandContent_main">    
  <xsl:param name="desc" select="/bodyText"/>
  <xsl:param name="separator" select="'<hr/>'"/>
  <xsl:param name="shortDesc" select="substring-before($desc, $separator)"/>
  <xsl:param name="longDesc" select="substring-after($desc, $separator)"/>
  <div class="short-description">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$shortDesc"/>
  </div>
  <div class="long-description">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$longDesc"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

The expected output:

```
<div class="short-description">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Short</p>
</div>
<div class="long-description">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Long</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your expected output. Also indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Is there always **exactly** one `<hr/>` tag in `<bodyText>`?

Comment: Yeah, we can consider that a rule. There's only one <hr/> tag. Tied to XSLT 1.0 for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<xsl:template match="bodyText">
  <div class="short-description">
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()[following-sibling::hr]"/>
  </div>
  <div class="long-description">
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()[preceding-sibling::hr]"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>`

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is that you are trying to use string functions on nodes. Now, I don't think you need a named template for this. Consider the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bodyText">
    <div class="short-description">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="p[not(preceding-sibling::hr)]"/>
    </div>
    <div class="long-description">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="p[preceding-sibling::hr]"/>
    </div>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following test input:

```
<content>
    <bodyText>
        <p>Lorem <i>Ipsum</i> Short</p>
        <hr/>
        <p>Lorem <b>Ipsum</b> Long</p>
    </bodyText>
</content>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content>
   <div class="short-description">
      <p>Lorem <i>Ipsum</i> Short</p>
   </div>
   <div class="long-description">
      <p>Lorem <b>Ipsum</b> Long</p>
   </div>
</content>
```

Comment: Definite +1 for your note about using string functions on nodes. Really appreciate it.